# Configure max retries for Infinispan Hot Rod Client

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, jboss6.x, infinispan, jboss-eap-6

I am using a JBoss EAP 6.3 application server in conjunction with a JDG 6.3.1 (with Infinispan 6.1.2), both instances run on the same virtual machine and the connection protocol is Hot Rod.

If for whatever reason the JDG is not reachable I want the Hot Rod Client used in an EJB application on the EAP to catch the `HotRodClientException` and continue directly with a database call.
This works fine but the retry count in the RemoteCacheManager is set to 10 so that it takes a lot of time until I can continue after the connection finally failed after 10 retries.

Looking at the classes involved I was not able to find a way to configure the max retry count for a Hot Rod connection. The only thing I found is using `ConfigurationBuilder.withProperties(Properties)`, but it is mentioned that this is for migrating from an old version of Inifinispan where properties objects where used for configuration.
I tried the following code but it also fails in setting the rety count to 1:

```
Properties jdgProperties = new Properties();
jdgProperties.put("infinispan.client.hotrod.server_list", host + ":" + hotrodPort);
jdgProperties.put("infinispan.client.hotrod.max_retries", "1");
Configuration jdgConfWithProperties = builder.withProperties(jdgProperties).build();
```

How can I configure the retry count to anything but the default value of 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().maxRetries(2).build();
RemoteCacheManager remoteCacheManager = new RemoteCacheManager(configuration);
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I'm using the Hot Rod Client to access the JDG in client-server mode and the `org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder` has no method maxRetries.

Comment: @devrys are you sure you are using the 6.3.1 hotrod client?

Comment: Maven import for infinispan-bom is version 6.0.2.Final and from this I get the artifact `infinispan-client-hotrod`, version 6.0.2.Final also.
Switching to infinispan-bom version 7.0.3.Final now yields a ConfigurationBuilder with a `maxRetries` method, but using this now throws a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.maxRetries(I)Lorg/infinispan/client/hotrod/configuration/ConfigurationBuilder;`

Comment: I suppose you have some mismatch with the versions on your classpath, because 7.0 versions have the method, see https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/7.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/configuration/ConfigurationBuilder.html#maxRetries%28int%29 .

Comment: That's true, but my problem might be that I am using a RemoteCacheManager und the Infinispan version on the JDG which I connect to is version 6.1.1 (I've seen that via JMX). Since I am not able to upgrade to a newer JDG or Infinispan version I can't set the max-retries.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted becauseit it's the right way to set max-retries programmatically, even though it doesn't match my use case.